# Meaning of "SAME" in the title of patent

Tags: title

Encountered multiple times, that title of patent has "...SAME" in the end. Tried searching, but you know Google (and SO), it only shows Q&A related to same patents.

I.E.
https://worldwide.espacenet.com/searchResults?query=US201615204907

1. GRAPHENE SYNTHESIS CHAMBER AND METHOD OF SYNTHESIZING GRAPHENE BY USING THE **SAME**

What does it mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in this context SAME means the graphene  synthesis chamber.

Comment: is it some kind of non-written rule to substitute something with same?

Comment: I'd say grammar. I understand it like that to.